# How to force ETW to send previously missed events

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, trace, etw

I want to capture file reads using ETW `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File` provider. It appears that I need to correlate 2 types of events using `FileObject` (or `FileKey`) property:

**Name create**

```
{
    "Type": "name create",
    "FileObject": 123,
    "FileName": "\\Device\\HarddiskVolume3\\file.txt"
}
```

**Read**

```
{
    "Type": "read",
    "FileObject": 123,
    ...
}
```

Which I can combine into a `file read` event

```
{
    "Type": "file read",
    "FileObject": 123,
    "FileName": "\\Device\\HarddiskVolume3\\file.txt",
    ...
}
```

The problem is that I only receive `name create` events for newly opened files. If a file has not been closed I will not get a `name create` event and it is impossible to corelate `read` event to get a file name. That information has been provided with `name create` before my subscriber was attached.

**Question:** Is it possible to force ETW to send all the events required for such correlation?  In other words, how can my subscriber retrieved cached `name create` events from the past?

I am using C++, [krabs](https://github.com/Microsoft/krabsetw/tree/master/krabs/krabs), `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File {EDD08927-9CC4-4E65-B970-C2560FB5C289}` provider (which is undocumented). I've experimented with kernel providers: [disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363703(v=vs.85).aspx) and [file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363884(v=vs.85).aspx) and it seems the correlation problem is there as well.

Comment: Hi did you find a workaround for this? I have the exact same problem and setup like yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet... That idea is not being actively developed just now, pls let me know if you find a solution to this

Comment: I have tried couple of things like duplicating the fileobject and querying it for the name but more than often it didn't work. Upvoted and bookmarked your question.

Comment: I remember I was looking for a `flush`, I thought there must be a table somewhere in Windows kernel where OS maintains this. I thought there could be a way to trigger an event when all the contents of that table would be sent to the listener. But that was just an idea, never found a way to implement it